# Split a text to a list after passing through \keys_define

Tags: expl3, latex3, xparse

I'm trying to create a command with key-value arguments with the second one is a list of items separated by commas.

The list is printed normally when I passed it directly to the `\DrawList` command, which has a `\SplitList` processor and a `\ProcessList` command. However, if the text is parsed by the `\keys_define` before being splitted, it seems to ignore the comma and the processor cannot split it at all.

How can I make it print like the `\DrawList` command? It's also great if anyone has a better alternative to make the interface easier. Thank you all.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\usepackage{enumitem}
\NewDocumentCommand\DrawList{>{\SplitList{,}}m}{
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep, topsep=0pt]
        \ProcessList{#1}{\item}
    \end{itemize}
}

\keys_define:nn {module_name}{
    ,1 .tl_set:N  = \__title
    ,2 .tl_set:N  = \__list
}

\NewDocumentCommand \TitleAndList {O{}}{
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn {module_name}{#1}
    \tl_if_empty:NF {\__title}{%
        \__title :\par
    }
    \tl_if_empty:NF {\__list}{%
        \DrawList{\__list}
    }
    \group_end:
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\DrawList{{First item, with a comma}, {Second item}}

---

\TitleAndList[
    1=Include,
    2={{First item, with a comma}, {Second item}}
]

---

\TitleAndList[1=Not a list]

---

\TitleAndList[2=An item]

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

No luck with lower-layer code:

```tex
\seq_new:N \list_sequence
\NewDocumentCommand\DrawList{m}{
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \list_sequence{,}{#1}
    \begin{itemize}
        \seq_map_function:NN \list_sequence \item
    \end{itemize}
}
```

Comment: `\DrawList{item1, item2}` is different from `\DrawList{\__list}`. In the latter case you need expand `\__list` first. Either `\expandafter\DrawList\expandafter{\__list}` or in latex3's style `\exp_args:No \DrawList{\__list}` will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the only time when you call `\DrawList` with a variable containing the list is inside of your own code you can simply use `\exp_args:NV` or `\exp_args:No` (the latter is fine if you know that the variable is a token list).

If you also want the user interface macro to be able to work on macros storing the list you could define your own processor.

The following does both, alter your `\TitleAndList` to expand the variable you forward to `\DrawList` and define a processor and uses it for `\otherDrawList`.

Please note that your variables should follow naming conventions of `expl3`, that is local variables (like yours) should start with `\l`, internal variables should have two underscores followed by the module name, a short description of the variable, and end in the abbreviated variable type. So the following is a correct name: `\l__thanhph_title_tl` (a local variable of module `thanhph` storing something called `title`, and it's a token list).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \thanhphSplitList #1 #2
  {
    \tl_if_single_token:nTF {#2}
      {
        \tl_if_head_is_space:nTF {#2}
          { \SplitList {#1} {#2} }
          {
            \token_if_expandable:NTF #2
              { \exp_args:Nno \SplitList {#1} {#2} }
              { \SplitList {#1} {#2} }
          }
      }
      { \SplitList {#1} {#2} }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \otherDrawList { >{\thanhphSplitList{,}}m }
  {
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep, topsep=0pt]
      \ProcessList{#1}{\item}
    \end{itemize}
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \DrawList { >{\SplitList{,}}m }
  {
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep, topsep=0pt]
      \ProcessList{#1}{\item}
    \end{itemize}
  }

\keys_define:nn { thanhph }
  {
    ,1 .tl_set:N  = \l__thanhph_title_tl
    ,2 .tl_set:N  = \l__thanhph_list_tl
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \TitleAndList {O{}}
  {
    \group_begin:
      \keys_set:nn { thanhph } {#1}
      \tl_if_empty:NF \l__thanhph_title_tl
        { \l__thanhph_title_tl :\par }
      \tl_if_empty:NF \l__thanhph_list_tl
        { \exp_args:No \DrawList \l__thanhph_list_tl }
    \group_end:
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\newcommand\mylist{one item, another item}

\begin{document}

\otherDrawList\mylist

---

\DrawList{{First item, with a comma}, {Second item}}

---

\TitleAndList[
    1=Include,
    2={{First item, with a comma}, {Second item}}
]

---

\TitleAndList[1=Not a list]

---

\TitleAndList[2={An item, another}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another solution could be to use a starred form if you want to expand the first token of the mandatory argument once. One can create this rather neatly, since `ltcmd`/`xparse` allows to reference other arguments inside the processors, so we could use `\IfBooleanT{#1}\exp_args:Nno\SplitList{,}` as the processor:

```
\NewDocumentCommand \DrawList
  { s >{ \IfBooleanT {#1} \exp_args:Nno \SplitList {,} } m }
  {
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep, topsep=0pt]
      \ProcessList{#2}{\item}
    \end{itemize}
  }
```

and then use

```
\DrawList*\mylist
```

to get the same result as in `\otherDrawList\mylist`.

---

If you don't need the `\DrawList` at all but only intend to use `\TitleAndUse` as an interface you can directly map to a `clist` (provided that you don't need the list as a token list and this is the only intended usage):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { thanhph }
  {
    ,1 .tl_set:N  = \l__thanhph_title_tl
    ,2 .clist_set:N  = \l__thanhph_list_clist
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \TitleAndList {O{}}
  {
    \group_begin:
      \keys_set:nn { thanhph } {#1}
      \tl_if_empty:NF \l__thanhph_title_tl
        { \l__thanhph_title_tl :\par }
      \clist_if_empty:NF \l__thanhph_list_clist
        { \__thanhph_typeset_list: }
    \group_end:
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__thanhph_typeset_list:
  {
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep, topsep=0pt]
      \item % one \item in front of the first clist element
      \clist_use:Nn \l__thanhph_list_clist \item % and one \item in front of the rest
    \end{itemize}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\newcommand\mylist{one item, another item}

\begin{document}

\TitleAndList[
    1=Include,
    2={{First item, with a comma}, {Second item}}
]

---

\TitleAndList[1=Not a list]

---

\TitleAndList[2={An item, another}]

\end{document}
```

See [the answer of @egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/625364) for shorter version of this approach.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Look like my quick-and-dirty strategy to switch to LaTeX3 with only `xparse` document wasn't quite sufficient, I should read the interface book now :>. Just an extra question: can I merge the `\TitleAndList` with the `\DrawList` if I take that approach? I only call it once from the `\TitleAndList` command.

Comment: @thanhph111 should your `\TitleAndList` have more possible keys than the two in your question? If it only gets two keys you could as well drop the key=value interface and use two mandatory arguments.

Comment: @thanhph111 see my edit on how I'd probably manage your list.

Comment: Great! I guess I can now put the `\begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize}`  after the `\clist_if_empty:NF` without create a new extra function. My `\TitleAndList` actually has other 3 parameters in the real document. I've tried `{ o o o o o }` but a lot of `[]` force me to use key-value interface.

Comment: @thanhph111 yes, if you need more options a key=value interface is much better, of course. And yes, you could put the replacement text of `\__thanhph_typeset_list:` inside the second argument of `\clist_if_empty:NF`.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect a clist as the value for a key, define it as such.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\DrawList{m}
 {
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep, topsep=0pt]
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { \item ##1 }
  \end{itemize}
 }

\keys_define:nn { thanhph/lists }
 {
  1 .tl_set:N    = \l__thanhph_lists_title_tl,
  2 .clist_set:N = \l__thanhph_lists_list_clist,
}

\NewDocumentCommand \TitleAndList {O{}}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { thanhph/lists } { #1 }
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l__thanhph_lists_title_tl 
   {
    \l__thanhph_lists_title_tl \par
   }
   \clist_if_empty:NF \l__thanhph_lists_list_clist
    {
     \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*, noitemsep, topsep=0pt]
     \clist_map_inline:Nn \l__thanhph_lists_list_clist { \item ##1 }
     \end{itemize}
    }
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Just the list}

\DrawList{{First item, with a comma}, {Second item}}

\subsubsection*{Title and list}

\TitleAndList[
    1=Include,
    2={{First item, with a comma}, {Second item}}
]

\subsubsection*{Only title}

\TitleAndList[1=Not a list]

\subsubsection*{Only list}

\TitleAndList[2={An item,Another item}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, it's really short. Is `O{}` equivalent to `o` and does the commas before `1`, `2` matter?

Comment: @thanhph111 no `O{}` defaults to an empty argument, whereas `o` defaults to a special marker that'll print out as -NoValue- (but is constructed such that is not equal to the input `-NoValue-`). And the commas at the start or end of the line don't make a difference here, that's just a preference of some people.